# useEffect to show snackbar if message is not null, and how to use useState with that?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have made a component to render out if message is not null and show snackbar. I have integrated it if someone clicks on Log In button, and if there is an error the error message should be prompted by snackbar. But when user clicks on snackbar and closed it the snackbar can not be showed up again if user again clicks on Log in button. It works well when user clicks for first time on Log in button, but other times it wont show up. "text" in my case is error message that i send trough props. So useEffect thinks that const "text" is not null and thats why if user clicks again on Log in button the snack bar doesnt show up. So my question is how can i bypass this, if message is the same, and show again snack bar whatever the message is?

This is a code that i have been using:

```
const NotificationManager = (props) => {
  const { text, type } = props
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(true)
  useEffect(() => {
    setOpen(Boolean(text))

  }, [Boolean(text)])
  const handleClose = () =>{
    setOpen(false)
}
  console.log(Boolean(text))
  return (
    <Snackbar
    onClick={handleClose}
      anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'bottom', horizontal: 'right' }}
      autoHideDuration={3000}
      open={open}
      snackbarcontentprops={{
        'aria-describedby': 'snackbar-message-id'
      }}
    >
      <SnackbarContent
        style={Object.assign({
          background: styles[type] || styles['success']
        })}
        message={localize(text)}
      />
    </Snackbar>
  )
}

export default NotificationManager
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question, you can accomplish it by adding another `useEffect` which resets your `open` state when you hiding your notification:

```js
const AUTO_HIDE_DURATION = 3000;

const NotificationManager = ({ text, isLoginClicked }) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(true);

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setOpen(Boolean(text));
  }, [Boolean(text)]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (open) {
        setOpen(!open);
      }
    }, AUTO_HIDE_DURATION);
  });

  return (
    <Snackbar
      onClick={handleClose}
      autoHideDuration={AUTO_HIDE_DURATION}
      open={open || isLoginClicked}
    >
      <SnackbarContent message={localize(text)} />
    </Snackbar>
  );
};

export default NotificationManager;
```

Note: You should upload your code to sandbox like [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io), we don't know about other props and their effects on your component state.

Comment: Once I click on snackbar and close it i can't manage to open it again ,because message is still the same. So i need to open it again when click on login button second time and so on...

Comment: Try introducing another prop which updates on your login button, check `isLoginClicked`

Answer (score 0):

First, `NotificationManager` has zero idea whether user has click on the login button or not. So it shouldn't keep `open` state internal.

You should move `useState` one level up to, say `LoginContainer`, then pass `[open, setOpen]` pair down into `NotificationManager` as props. This way, both components can access `setOpen`, whenever user click login, just `setOpen(true)`.

Second, you have 2 boolean state variables, 4 possible combinations

```
                open: true  open: false
text: true      true        false
text: false     false       false
```

Answer is quite obvious, you should just quit use `open` as the final toggling state variable. That `useEffect` is totally unnecessary. Instead use:

```
const reallyShouldOpen = Boolean(text) & open;
```

Third, you should toggle `open` back to `false` when `autoHideDuration` ends, so when people click again they can re-toggle the thing. (same as @DannisVash suggests)

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (open) {
        setOpen(!open);
      }
    }, AUTO_HIDE_DURATION);
  });
```